# Reset author list and reference list for each paper in article class

Tags: biblatex, article, affiliation

I am aggregating different papers in one file using "article class". The problem I'm having is how to reset the list of references after each article. The error I'm facing now is that all references are printed when using command `\printbibliography`. How do I reset the reference lists after using `\printbibliography`?

There are also some minor errors in this code. Those are:

(i) the "abstract" and "keywords" sections pop up at the top of the first page;

(ii) The Title font of paper 2 is smaller and the author's affiliation of the 2nd paper is not displayed as you can seen in the picture below. Can anyone help me fix these errors? Thank you.

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,linkcolor = blue,filecolor = magenta,%
    urlcolor = cyan, citecolor = blue, unicode = true,}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords: }} #1}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE OF PAPER 1}

\author[1]{Nguyen Van One}
\affil[1]{Victoria University, New Zealand}

\date{}

\begin{abstract}

Abstract of paper 1 here.
\end{abstract}


\keywords{Climate change,  Mekong Delta}


\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Text for section of introduction. Cite for paper 1. \cite{greenwade93}

\printbibliography
%---------------------------------
% End of paper 1

%---------------------------------
%   Paper 2
%---------------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\AB@affillist}{}
\renewcommand{\AB@authlist}{}
\setcounter{authors}{0}
\setcounter{affil}{0}
\makeatother


\clearpage
\newpage

\title{TITLE OF PAPER 2}

\author[2]{Nguyen Van Two}
\affil[2]{Western Sydney University, Australia}

\date{}

\begin{abstract}

Abstract of paper 2 here.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Vulnerability, Resilience}

\maketitle

\setcounter{section}{0}


\section{Introduction}
Text for section of introduction. Cite for paper 2. \cite{dirac}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

sample.bib

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}

@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}
```

Compile: pdflatex -> bibtex > pdflatex -> pdflatex

Comment: Did you look at biblatex/biber? Sounds like that should not be difficult to achieve with that toolchain, but an uphill fight with just bibtex.

Comment: Please only ask about one issue per question. If you have multiple issues with your code, ask several questions: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: Can you explain the *exact* requirements for the bibliographies of the different papers in more detail, please? Are the bibliographies for the two papers supposed to be completely independent. (I.e. can the same source have different citation numbers in each paper?) Do you need a complete list of references at the end that includes the references from both papers?

Comment: Yes, the bibliographies for two papers are independent as you mentioned.
For instance, at the each paper One, I want to print the bibliography of paper One only and at the en of paper Two will print the bibliography which are cited just in paper Two. Tks

Answer (score 2):

Use `refsection`s to keep the bibliographies of the different papers apart. `refsection`s allow you to generate completely independent citations and bibliographies in the same document.

In this case this should be as easy as wrapping each paper in `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}`. Everything else is taken care of automatically (e.g. the `\printbibliography` is local to the current `refsection`.)

If you have multiple `refsection`s, you should use Biber as backend and not BibTeX. While BibTeX does support multiple refsections, the compiler setup you will need is much more complicated, since BibTeX needs to be run on different `.aux` files (one for each `refsection`). Biber, on the other hand, needs to be run only once.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,linkcolor = blue,filecolor = magenta,%
    urlcolor = cyan, citecolor = blue, unicode = true,}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords: }} #1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\title{TITLE OF PAPER 1}

\author[1]{Nguyen Van One}
\affil[1]{Victoria University, New Zealand}

\date{}

\begin{abstract}

Abstract of paper 1 here.
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Climate change,  Mekong Delta}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Text for section of introduction. Cite for paper 1. \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
%---------------------------------
% End of paper 1

\clearpage
\begin{refsection}
%---------------------------------
%   Paper 2
%---------------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\AB@affillist}{}
\renewcommand{\AB@authlist}{}
\setcounter{authors}{0}
\setcounter{affil}{0}
\makeatother

\title{TITLE OF PAPER 2}

\author[2]{Nguyen Van Two}
\affil[2]{Western Sydney University, Australia}

\date{}

\begin{abstract}

Abstract of paper 2 here.
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Vulnerability, Resilience}

\maketitle
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Introduction}
Text for section of introduction. Cite for paper 2. \cite{worman}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @moewe. It works for me.